# Hibernate example query incorrectly formed

Tags: java, hibernate

User.hbm.xml

```
<class name="dataAccess.User" table="USER" schema="PUBLIC" catalog="XYZ">
    <id name="userId" type="long">
        <column name="USER_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="userName" type="string">
        <column name="USER_NAME" length="25" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="emailId" type="string">
        <column name="EMAIL_ID" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="PASSWORD" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="admin" type="char">
        <column name="ADMIN" length="1" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastLoginTime" type="timestamp">
        <column name="LAST_LOGIN_TIME" length="23" />
    </property>
```

My data access function

```
public List findByExample(User instance) {
    log.debug("finding User instance by example");
    try {
        List results = sessionFactory.openSession()
                .createCriteria("dataAccess.User")
                .add(Example.create(instance)).list();
        System.out.println(results.size());
        log.debug("find by example successful, result size: "
                + results.size());
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("find by example failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

I am only passing two out of the 6 attributes of the User class(username and password). But in the query it also checks for the admin field. It works fine if i put an exclude("admin") to the criteria. I cant quite figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Is something in the User class setting or changing the admin field? Such as the getter providing a default value?

Comment: @StormcrowSX No its not. I am getting the username password from the form, populating it in the User object and passing it to the method. I tried printing out the values of each attribute in the object. Only username and password have values, rest are all null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.

The default value for char is '\u0000'. The create criteria excludes the field only if the value is found to be null. If i change it to String, it works fine.

Comment: Changing it to the object Character instead of the primitive char probably would have worked as well.  In general its easier to avoid primitives altogether in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Given the mapping of the admin field, we can assume that it is of type boolean. A boolean is either true of false, but never null. Why would the value of this field not be part of the example? Hibernate can't assume that false means "I want to ignore this field" and that true means "I want to find the users whose admin flag is true". You might very well look for the users whose admin flag is false.

Comment: I have defined admin field as character and not boolean.